# Why doesn't my change of coordinate method from linear algebra work with spherical coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, change-of-basis

I would like to change the linear function
$$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$$ to spherical coordinates. In Cartesian basis its expressed as $$T_{Cartesian} = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
By the method of changing basis I learnt from linear algebra,
$$\begin{align*}T_{Spherical} &= \begin{pmatrix}sinΘcosΦ&sinΘsinΦ&cosΘ\\rcosΘcosΦ&rcosΘsinΦ&-rsinΘ\\-rsinΘsinΦ&rsinΘcosΦ&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}sinΘcosΦ&rcosΘsinΦ&-rsinΘsinΦ\\sinΘsinΦ&rcosΘsinΦ&rsinΘcosΦ\\cosΘ&-rsinΘ&0\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&r^2&0\\0&0&r^2 \sin^2Θ\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$
Giving (in natural basis, not orthonormal) $$\mathbf{F}(r,Θ,Φ)=r\mathbf{r}+r^2Θ\textbf{Θ}+r^2Φ\sin^2Θ\textbf{Φ}$$
Which is not correct because it should be
$$\mathbf{F}(r,Θ,Φ)=r\mathbf{r}$$

*Edit: thanks to Arturo, I have added this below:

But this method works:
$$\begin{align*}T_{Spherical} &= \begin{pmatrix}sinΘcosΦ&sinΘsinΦ&cosΘ\\rcosΘcosΦ&rcosΘsinΦ&-rsinΘ\\-rsinΘsinΦ&rsinΘcosΦ&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}rsinΘcosΦ\\rsinΘsinΦ\\rcosΘ\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$
Which is just the change of basis of vector, but not a transformation.

Can anyone tell me did I do it right? Why doesn't the first approach work? Why does the second work?

Comment: The expression of a vector in terms of spherical coordinates is not linear in the arguments. If $(a,b,c)$ corresponds to the spherical data $(r,\phi,\theta)$, and $(a',b',c')$ corresponds to $(r',\phi',\theta')$, then it is not necessarily the case that $(a+a',b+b',c+c')$ corresponds to $(r+r',\phi+\phi',\theta+\theta')$, nor does $(ka,kb,kc)$ correspond to $(kr,k\phi,k\theta)$. This is not a linear change of coordinates, so the methods of linear algebra are not applicable.

Comment: Thanks! Hi Arturo, can you see my edit? Why does the second approach work?

Comment: 1. What you wrote is wrong. The dimensions don't match. 2. Either your matrix changes with each vector (which means it isn't any kind of "change of basis matrix"), or else this is an equality valid for a *single* vector with particular arguments, in which case it *also* is not any kind of "change of basis" in the sense of linear algebra.

Comment: A change of basis matrix would take the standard basis and express it in terms of **specific values** of $r$, $\Phi$, and $\Theta$. The entries would be *numbers*, not formulas. You are not doing linear algebra in your calculations, and what you are trying to apply linear algebra to is not a setting where linear algebra applies. You are incorrect both coming and going here.